# OpenCV StereoSGBM parameters for 25 MP Images

Tags: opencv

I'm able to perform stereovision with two webcams and get good disparity map and 3D Point Cloud Reconstruction using the following parameters:

```
 Ptr<StereoSGBM> sgbm = StereoSGBM::create(0,    //int minDisparity
                                    96,     //int numDisparities
                                    5,      //int SADWindowSize
                                    600,    //int P1 = 0
                                    2400,   //int P2 = 0
                                    20,     //int disp12MaxDiff = 0
                                    16,     //int preFilterCap = 0
                                    1,      //int uniquenessRatio = 0
                                    100,    //int speckleWindowSize = 0
                                    20,     //int speckleRange = 0
                                    true);  //bool fullDP = false
```

I've now abandoned webcams and I am working with 25 MP images (**5012 x 5012**) that are very large and am not able to get good disparity as I was able to do for the webcams. This of course depends on the parameters of the StereoSGBM employed for computing disparity.

Could anybody suggest me a good starting point with reasonable numeric values of parameters I should replace in this constructor in order to have StereoSGBM perform well on these super large images?

Any help will be highly appreciated